# Does linker do relocation for functions that are referenced but not actually called in the program?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

I was told that:

***If your program references 10 functions in the library but calls 0 of them, the difference in lazy binding vs immediate binding is 0 vs 10 lookup. If your program references 100 functions in the library but only calls 10 of them, the difference is 10 vs 100 lookup.***

below is my code and my understanding:

**main.c**

```
// this program references func_lib but doesn't call func_main

void func_lib();

void func_main()
{
     func_lib();
}

int main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

**mylibrary.c**

```
void func_lib()
{
   ...
}
```

and a shared library `mylibrary.so` is produced based on `mylibrary.c`, and let's link `main.c` and `mylibrary.so` into executable file called `prog`, so according to quoted text, `func_lib` is referenced but not called by the program, without lazy binding, there is one lookup(I think lookup means relocation performed by the linker) for `func_lib`

But I checked `prog` using `readelf`, there is no entry in `.rel.text`, no entry of `func_lib` in any section of `prog`, since the program doesn't even call `func_main`, which means that the linker won't do any lookup/ relocation for `func_lib`?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/607939/does-linker-do-relocations-for-functions-that-are-referenced-but-not-called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A declaration does not reference anything. All a function declaration does is tell the compiler how to handle `func_lib`s arguments and return value if it is called; that information is irrelevant if the function is not called. (Which is usually the case for much of the standard library.)

For there to be a reference, you actually have to use the symbol in some way -- for example, include a function which calls `func_lib`. (It doesn't matter if the function itself is never called, as long as it has external linkage and thus could be called from some other translation unit.)

Comment: thanks for your answer. Still a little bit confused, let's say `func_main` is defined in `main.c` and `func_main` call `func_lib` inside. If `main.c` doesn't call `func_main`, the compile won't even do any work for `func_main`, still there is no relocation entry for `func_lin` as a consequence?

Comment: @amjad: If the compiler can eliminate the body of `func_main` because it can prove that it is never called, then any external references in that function will also be eliminated. But if `func_main` has external linkage, then the compiler cannot know that it will not be called from some other translation unit which will be linked with `main.c`. At least, that's my theory :-)

Comment: @amjad: I just tried it with gcc-10 -O3, and it indeed works the way I thought it would: with `static func_main`, `func_lib` is not present in the compiled code. But with `func_main` externally linked, the linker complains about `func_lib` not being defined and the link step fails.